# ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 reference LESS files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, less, intellisense

I just installed the [ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/02/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-update.aspx).

It finally provides first-class support for editing LESS files, complete with syntax highlighting, Intellisense, and validation.

My problem is, that my mixins and variables files are in seperate files and bundling is done dynamically, so that Intellisense isn't kicking in for them. How can I add a reference to these files in my LESS files without using `@import`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add references to your LESS files similar like you would do it for JavaScript files in Visual Studio:

```
/// <reference path="../../_variables.less" />
```

Comment: It seems like using references from "_references.less" is not supported :(